# Hosting Legacy ASP.NET (Framework) images with Docker over HTTPS

Tags: docker, windows-container

I have found this URL

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-7.0

for hosting ASP .NET core images with docker over https but unable to find any articles to host legacy .NET applications with windows container over https. Any idea on how to host legacy .NET applications with windows container over https

Comment: If it's IIS hosted, then there's a small example Dockerfile here: https://github.com/microsoft/iis-docker. It's just http though.

Comment: If this is IIS, you can manage it as a regular IIS server. On a Windows container you don't have a UI, so you'd need to execute the IIS commands via PowerShell. That should be in your docker file.
The other alternative is to use a remote management for the container. I created a blog post describing it here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/5-tips-for-iis-on-containers-bonus-iis-remote-management/ba-p/3692044 From IIS you can edit the website bindings just like you would for an IIS server.